# Firebase CLI tool is freezing when I type 'firebase init'

Tags: firebase, terminal, firebase-tools

I installed the firebase command line tool and logged in successfully. I type

```
   firebase init
```

in terminal, within my project directory, and I get the option to choose Database, Functions, or Hosting. I use the arrows and space bar to select Functions, press enter, and am presented with a list of projects. From this point forward I cannot do anything in terminal. I have to quit terminal in order to use it again. I am running OSX El Capitan, 10.11.6. I contacted Apple Support and they recommended talking with Firebase first, who in turn recommends asking stack overflow first. Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: What Node version do you have? Node v8.0 and Node v8.1 both had regressions that broke Firebase CLI. If you have either of these, please upgrade to Node v8.1.1 or later.

Comment: Version 8.1.0 currently. I'll try upgrading and post an update.

Comment: I installed 8.1.3. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See the comment above, Node v8.0 and 8.1 both had regressions that broke the Firebase CLI. I upgraded my version of Node from 8.1.0 to 8.1.3, and everything works fine.

Comment: I tried this solution but did not work. I am on ubuntu and installed the mentioned version using nvm.